# Formatting Sybase Resultset into specific amount of columns

Tags: shell, format, sybase, resultset, isql

I have a sybase query in a shell script that is only supposed to produce 2 columns in the result set. I save the result set into a variable then send that output to a file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
>newfile.sh
SERVERNAME=myserver
LOGINNAME=mylogin
PASSWORD=mypwd
var1=$(isql -S${SERVERNAME] -U${LOGINNAME} -P${PASSWORD} -w 15 <<EOF
select column1, column2 from table1
select column1, column2 from table2 

go
EOF
)
echo $var1 >>newfile.sh
exit 0
```

I get my results but it does not come out with the 2 columns that I intended. Instead it looks like this.

```
column1 column2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 column 1 column2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2 results1 results2
```

How can I get it to be in this format? I used the -w flag to limit each line to 15 characters but that doesn't seem to work.

```
column1 column 2 
results1 results2
results1 results2
results1 results2
results1 results2
results1 results2
```

Comment: Can you try double-quoting `$var` as `"$var"` to reflect the new-lines present?

Comment: That worked. The results get sent to the newfile.sh as 2 columns. I'm still getting the column names and the the number of rows in the results, but I'll have to find a way to get rid of that somehow. Thank you. This helped. How does double-quotes reflect the new lines present? I've never seen that on other forums.

Comment: Refer the `bash` man page entries for the reason explaining.